# What's the idiomatic way to compare fields based only on interfaces disregarding underlying types (there isn't a "cmpopts.UseInterfaceOnly()")?

Tags: go

I have a bunch of data structs that all adhere to an interface, and I'd like to write a unit test that can work on all implementations.

This is a case where, if I'd use the same struct type, I'd want to use cmp.Diff, but I can't find a way to tell cmp to compare based on interface surface.

Toy example:

```
type Person interface {
    Name() string
    Age() int
}

type yearlyPerson struct {
    name     string
    yearsOld int
}

type dailyPerson struct {
    name    string
    daysOld int
}

func (dp *dailyPerson) Age() int {
    return dp.daysOld / 365
}

// Other 3 functions are trivial field returns.
```

If we pretend there are many such fields, in a unit test, I might want to use `cmp.Diff` to nicely capture and display any discrepancies it picks up, but IIUC, `cmp` only ever focuses on concrete types.

Is there an idiomatic way to do interface-field-based comparisons? I didn't look too hard, but I haven't found a "cmp/cmpopts but for interface surfaces specifically" library.

Off the top of my head, the best I can think of is a helper library that manually constructs a concrete type with exported fields matching the interface surface, and then using `cmp.Diff` accordingly, like I do here: https://go.dev/play/p/TtEomRGXTtQ

Is this the best way, or is there something much better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cmp.Diff` is specifically looking at data. An interface, ignoring the underlying type, has no data. It only has methods. Only concrete types have fields.

> interface-field-based comparison

does not exist; interfaces do not have fields.

> constructs a concrete type with exported fields matching the interface surface

does not exist; the interface surface is only methods and specifies no fields. You can do this manually because you know which methods are just getters/setters for underlying fields, but runtime tooling can't make that assumption. Most interfaces do not specify getters/setters, as that's not generally what they're for; they're for specifying behavior.

So, essentially, what you're describing can only realistically be achieved by writing the comparison yourself for each interface type, as you've done in your example.

Comment: got it, thanks. I just figured there might be a commonly-used library that did this, given that reflect knows how to understand interfaces.

Comment: Unfortunately not - reflect can understand interfaces, but Go has no concept of "properties" like C#/Java, so reflect doesn't know if a method is a getter/setter or something else entirely.